# How to unpromote package from Release view?

Tags: tfs, nuget

I add package to feed with version 1 and promote it to @Release view.

Then, i add package to feed with version 2 and promote it to @Release_1.

Then, i want to remove package from @Release_1 view (and, may be, promote it to @Release_2 ) . But i can not find how to do that.

Please, tell me how to unpromote package from view.

Thank you.

I use TFS 2018.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to unpromote package from Release view currently, unless you delete the view.